# Почему метод inject() всегда логает в консоль ScssItd, причем даже если тега inject не сущ-ет

Tags: javascript

```
class InjectIo{
  injections =0;
  constructor(){
    
  }
  inject(){
    let inj=document.getElementsByTagName('inject')
    if(inj){
      console.log("ScssItd")
    }else{
      throw new Error('Injection failure')
    }
  }
}
let inj=new InjectIo()
inj.inject()
```

Comment: это новый синтексис создания класса без class? полный код вставь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что оператор `if` автоматически приводит указанное в нем выражение к типу `boolean`, а метод `getElementsByTagName` возвращает массивоподобный объект типа `HTMLCollection` (который, *как и любой другой объект кроме спецзначения null*, является истинным значением - даже когда коллекция пуста).

Другими словами: потому что `Boolean(любойОбъектКромеNull) === true`, всегда.

---

Вместо проверки истинности значения `if(inj)`, можно проверять длину коллекции: `if (inj.length > 0)` или просто `if (inj.length)`.

Comment: Теперь ВСЕГДА ТОЛЬКО Injection error

Comment: @РусскийПуп, очевидно в момент вызова метода, нужных элементов нет

Comment: Так случается даже если элемент есть

Comment: @РусскийПуп, а откуда уверенность что элемент есть? При том что факты явно говорят об обратном.

Comment: Я сам добавил тег в html :/

Comment: @РусскийПуп, HTML и DOM - не одно и то же. Тег и элемент - не одно и то же. Скрипт может вызываться **до** того, как документ "построил" все свои элементы из разметки. Помести скрипт в самый конец тела страницы, прямо перед закрывающим тегом `</body>`.

Comment: Попробуем document.createElement("inject")

Comment: @yar85,Можно...

Comment: @РусскийПуп, можно, и при понимании того что делает это выражение - прослушивание события будет даже лучше, т.к. исключит влияние разметки на порядок выполнения скрипта.

Comment: Можно ещё добавить ```document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',{code})```

Comment: Я конечно понимаю, что это значит

Comment: Все чудесным образом заработало!!!